# Converting Java sendEmail method to Groovy

Tags: grails, groovy

I have a Java method to send a file attachment via e-mail. I'm trying to port it to Groovy as part of a Grails application. I'm having issue with the format of the `FileDataSource` declaration. The offending code is marked with an asterisk. What's the proper way to do that part in Groovy? I can't seem to find anything on the web.

```
public static void sendEmail(String sendFile)
    {
    //
    // Send the log file via email.
    //
    final String username = "myname@mydomain.com"
    final String password = "mypassword"

    // Strings that contain from, to, subject, body and file path to the attachment
    String from = username;
    String subject = "Test Results"
    String body = "Body of Test Results email."
    String filename = sendFile

    // Set smtp properties
    Properties properties = new Properties()
    properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true")
    properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true")
    properties.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com")
    properties.put("mail.smtp.port", "587")

    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties, new javax.mail.Authenticator()
    {
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication()
        {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(username,password)
        }
    });

    try
    {
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session)
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from))
        // For debug uncomment the line below and enter your email address.
        //message.addRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse("peter.cook@studentuniverse.com"));
        // For debug comment the line below out.
        message.addRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse("cccm@studentuniverse.com,WebsiteOperations@studentuniverse.com,peter.cook@studentuniverse.com"))
        message.setSubject(subject)
        message.setSentDate(new Date())

        // Set the email body
        MimeBodyPart messagePart = new MimeBodyPart()
        messagePart.setText(body)

        // Set the email attachment file
        MimeBodyPart attachmentPart = new MimeBodyPart()
        *FileDataSource fileDataSource = new FileDataSource(filename)
        *{
        *    @Override
        *    public String getContentType()
        *    {
        *        return "application/octet-stream"
        *    }
        * }
        attachmentPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(fileDataSource))
        attachmentPart.setFileName(fileDataSource.getName())

        // Add all parts of the email to Multipart object
        Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart()
        multipart.addBodyPart(messagePart)
        multipart.addBodyPart(attachmentPart)
        message.setContent(multipart)

        // Send email
        Transport.send(message)
        System.out.println("Mail sent!")
    }
    catch (MessagingException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
}
```

Comment: Try putting the "{" on the same line as the `new FileDataSource(filename)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That awful brace style is conflicting with Groovy not requiring semicolons. No need for a non-anonymous class definition though unless it's going to be used more than once, just declare it like this:

```
FileDataSource fileDataSource = new FileDataSource(filename) {
    String getContentType() { 'application/octet-stream' }
}
```

Comment: Ahh, better than mine +1.  I knew there was a cleaner way just didn't want to mess around figuring out syntax.

Answer (score 0):

The code you point out is an anonymous inner class overriding a single method (getContentType) and groovy is probably having a little trouble dealing with it due to the fact that it looks like a "new object" with a closure after it.

If you want to stick with the java-ish look I'd recommend changing it from an anonymous inner class to a separate class.  Something like this outside of your other code in this class (It can be in the same file if it's not a public class):

```
    class ForceOctetStreamFileDataSource extends FileDataSource
    {
        public ForceOctetStreamFileDataSource(String filename) {
            super(filename);
        }

        @Override
        public String getContentType()
        {
            return "application/octet-stream"
        }
    }
```

then in your class replace it with just new ForceOctetStreamFileDataSource(filename)

This should be explicit enough not to confuse groovy.  There is probably a much shorter "Groovy" way involving closures that I don't want to guess at right now.

Answer (score 0):

Install the `mail` plugin by adding `compile 'org.grails.plugins:mail'` to your `build.gradle` and then read the doco [here](http://grails.org/plugin/mail).

In case you have trouble with the installation, try `compile 'org.grails.plugins:mail:2.0.0.RC1'`.

Then, for [smtp configuration](http://gpc.github.io/grails-mail/guide/2.%20Configuration.html#2.1%20SMTP%20Server%20Configuration), you will need to migrate it to config file :

If you are done , you should be able to send an email following snippet above  :

```
mailService.sendMail {
   to "fred@gmail.com","ginger@gmail.com"
   from "john@gmail.com"
   cc "marge@gmail.com", "ed@gmail.com"
   bcc "joe@gmail.com"
   subject "Hello John"
   text 'this is some text'
}
```